# ssh-copy-id specifying which key and without password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a public key in a server(**host**) that I want to transfer to another server(**target**).

The **host** server has a bunch of keys in `.ssh/` folder, i want to copy just one of them to the **target** server (it's not `id_rsa.pub`, so lets call `mykey.rsa.pub`).

Also, the target server has the host server key (lets call `hostkey.rsa.pub`) in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, for passwordless ssh.

Is it possible to do something like this?

`ssh-copy-id mykey.rsa.pub -i hostkey.rsa.pub user@target`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can pass `ssh` options with `-o`:

```
ssh-copy-id -i mykey.rsa.pub -o "IdentityFile hostkey.rsa" user@target
```

Comment: Worked for me but I had to add `-f` before `-i`.

Comment: it really makes no sense that it tries to copy every single key by default.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible something like

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i hostkey.rsa.pub user@target
```

with latest version of `ssh-copy-id`. If you have some older, it might or might not work (with RHEL7 and older Fedora with `SSH_COPY_ID_LEGACY=1` environment variable)

Comment: Also make sure the -i option is BEFORE user@target. -f might not be needed.

Comment: I think the OP wants to copy mykey.rsa.pub.  They want to use hostkey.rsa.pub for the underlying ssh connection during the copy....